# Typescript: Conditional return type

Tags: typescript

```
function customFetch<K extends keyof typeof PATH>(k:K, ...p:Parameters<typeof PATH[K]>):IReturnType[K]{
  const url = "baseurl" + (PATH[k] as any)(...p);
  return fetch(url);
}

function fetch(url:string):any{
  console.log("fetching "+url);
}

const PATH = {
  user: (id:number)=> `/user/${id}`,
  company: ()=> `/company`,
}

type IReturnType={
  user:UserType,
  company:CompanyType,
}

type UserType ={
  name:string,
  age:number
};

type CompanyType ={
  name:string,
  location:string
};

const u = customFetch("user",1);
const c = customFetch("company");
```

I am trying to write conditional return type for customFetch. So far I was able to make it work and get the desired function call signature. But for maintenance I have two issues which I couldn't fix.

1. In customFetch, without any, I am getting *A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter* error. Intput parameter type should be enough to guarantee correct call for path function. How can I fix this?
2. Path and IReturnType has 1 to 1 relationship. If I add new entry to Path, I get compile error. But If I have extra entries in IReturnType, it is not detected. How can I enforce IReturnType has same keys as Path while keeping their values?

**EDIT:**

Thank you for your suggestions.
It seems there isn't an easy way to fix the first one.
For the second, I used a dummy variable.

```
type Bind<A, B> = Omit<A & B, keyof (A | B)>;
const rule2:Bind<typeof PATH, IReturnType> = {};
```

Comment: What version of `tsc` are you using? It may be because it isn't new enough.

Comment: For (2), I can think of defining a dummy type that errors if `keyof IReturnType` is not a subset of `keyof typeof PATH`: `type Enforce<K extends keyof IReturnType> = typeof PATH[K]`, so the condition is enforced.

Comment: I tried it in TS playground with latest version(4.3.5). I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed the "without any" part. Basically TypeScript knows `K = "user" | "company"` and `k : K`, which means `k` is either `"user"` or `"company"`. It does not know which exactly it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Path and IReturnType has 1 to 1 relationship.

It is true, but, TS is unable to bind them, because `k` and `p` arguments are separate data structures.

I mean, they are not a part of one object or array.

In order to help TS to `bind` them, you should create a union type.

Smth like this `type Union = ["user", number] | ["company", undefined]`

```js
const PATH = {
  user: (id: number) => `/user/${id}`,
  company: () => `/company`,
}
type PATH = typeof PATH

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type Union = Values<{
  [P in keyof typeof PATH]: [P, Parameters<PATH[P]>[0]]
}>
```

Now, TS is able to find relations between them:

```js
const PATH = {
  user: (id: number) => `/user/${id}`,
  company: () => `/company`,
}
type PATH = typeof PATH

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type Union = Values<{
  [P in keyof typeof PATH]: [P, Parameters<PATH[P]>[0]]
}>

const BASE = "baseurl"

function customFetch(props: Union) {
  if (props[0] === 'user') {
    return fetch(`${BASE}${PATH[props[0]](props[1])}`)
  } else {
    return fetch(`${BASE}${PATH[props[0]]()}`)
  }
}
```

But we still have a problem with ReturnType. In order to do that we can use [function-overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads)

Pls, keep in mind, function intersecion also producec overloads:

```js
const PATH = {
  user: <T extends number>(id: T) => `/user/${id}` as const,
  company: () => `/company`,
}
type PATH = typeof PATH


const BASE = "baseurl"

// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
  k: infer I
) => void
  ? I
  : never;

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type Union = Values<{
  [P in keyof typeof PATH]: Parameters<PATH[P]>[0] extends undefined ? [P] : [P, Parameters<PATH[P]>[0]]
}>

type Overloading = UnionToIntersection<Values<{
  [P in keyof typeof PATH]: Parameters<PATH[P]>[0] extends undefined ? (key: P) => IReturnType[P] : (key: P, p: Parameters<PATH[P]>[0]) => IReturnType[P]
}>>

const customFetch: Overloading = (...props: Union) => {
  if (props[0] === 'user') {
    return fetch(`${BASE}${PATH[props[0]](props[1])}`)
  } else {
    return fetch(`${BASE}${PATH[props[0]]()}`)
  }
}

function fetch(url: string): any {
  return null as any
}

type IReturnType = {
  user: UserType,
  company: CompanyType,
}

type UserType = {
  name: string,
  age: number
};

type CompanyType = {
  name: string,
  location: string
};

const u = customFetch("user", 1);
const c = customFetch('company');
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBACgQQCoAkYF4YG8CwAoGGAVwgFMAnALhgB4kZSAPKUsAEwhjCIFsAjCgD4AFAEs21JAEoMgmAAMA9CQqKAJFnEBfeTACGnUJCgAafIVA8ADnrABPasJno5SyzfvyzeLfih2rUnhkNEx-QJAAM2DUfDi8I2gYACEEAGUAUQwYACI%20A1IicgAbHPjFRRhgclI2UShOAHMQUk4oEBgACygoKwhKCug9YABrEAA3CkjikAB3ADpLRT1FAFYABgBmAHZVgCYADgA2PwCggFUwUXAkEABJMBZyMmAoa7Aac7lMYXOGZlYHH09hgAH4YMIRtRzs45OMQOIYNQwKRJuQZEwWOxOMJzDAoTBRGBIhQYHd8LCYPDxHjweSCEiuKiKABueLhIIANT0xSIrTo3xgSAA2iNSHYokKALrss4wS7vbLc3n83AM4VwQlgfHiyUcyWIVBS6hwPTkPQ8UhPCA0Q0oDVSwTC9ZS-5YoFEdikSJE2pgmAOxkakzwM0Wq0UG12h1Ol0ynyCWWBGAAeTRMz0dTAjWyCpu90ekdIr3eNGVfJtasIGq1Ool0X10TtxtD5st1ttIRjztdmMBnE9bG9vrY-sh4pNlLuACUrUUwEgzoHHGKHPAQ1YTWH25HO6huy6p7OoPPF4EHfgtIJE3h8IlYMASO0eAAxK3ATrUNMUDNZnM-eZAKscgQD6aErnASkq0JaJhGA0CIB7DB0EwAByFRyFQmRoMIGoT3IbUSSgD9hHkDRUkyLQNGjeC%20h7KU4JAuiAEYpSkHQpDxLQGGKMhsDxXC5wImAiJIsisAojIqKwGimMQuMnA4rjL3iSJPRLcARPfTphCKYpqGgcgiUaKRqFsOx%20IZPD5y4IhimKfROHMlTbzwDkyWPU85UwaCMOhMhyDPUhvAsEBrHM6gAGEwo8Owgu8XxXPc84AqC7JoLAcMDKgIzsxC-RGlIZFeAEchLzZJK5Wi8L7DSny8Uyy1styxp8pmYA9DecBmuM8r4nvYhskfaAwrfYidJyDCchDZipAqgbgCGp9Ru04RUPccysJZIA)

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your second question is quite simple. You just have to get rid of the separate `IReturnType`:

```ts
function customFetch<
  K extends keyof typeof PATH
>(k: K, ...p: Parameters<typeof PATH[K]>): ReturnType<typeof PATH[K]> {
  const url = "baseurl" + (PATH[k] as any)(...p);
  return fetch(url);
}
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w2Kb1N)

As for the first question. I believe it's not possible now in typescript without exhaustive type narrowing. While at the call site typescript can take the concrete value of `k` and infer the rest types, inside the function body there is no concrete type `k` and `p` has type `Parameters<typeof PATH[K]>` depending on *unspecified* generic type parameter `K`. So until it knows the exact type of `K` (that you can do with type narrowing) it has opaque unreduced type it cannot reason about.