# Correct TS declaration for mapping fields together

Tags: typescript

I have an `AccountDefinition` that can look like this:

```js
something: {
  type: 'client',
  parameters: {
    foo: 3
  }
},
other: {
  type: 'user',
  parameters: {
    bar: 3
  }
},
...
```

The TS declaration works fine but I am now trying to make a "generator" (`doThings`) function and running into challenges on how to properly type it. I am open to refactoring all these types too.

```ts
export interface Spec {
  type: `${SpecType}`
  parameters: unknown
}

export interface UserSpec extends Spec {
  type: `${SpecType.USER}`
  parameters: UserSpecParameters
}

export interface ClientSpec extends Spec {
  type: `${SpecType.CLIENT}`
  parameters: ClientSpecParameters
}

export interface AccountDefinition {
  [k: string]: UserSpec | ClientSpec
}

export enum SpecType {
  USER = 'user',
  CLIENT = 'client'
}

export type SpecParametersMap = {
  user: {
    bar?: number
  }
  client: ClientSpecParameters
}

export interface UserSpecParameters {
  bar?: number
}

export interface ClientSpecParameters {
  foo: number
}

export const doThing = <T extends SpecType>( // Ideally not a generic if it can infer parameters from type
  type: T,
  parameters: SpecParametersMap[T]
): void => {
  const account: AccountDefinition = {
    // Example
    foo: {
      type: 'client',
      parameters: {
        foo: 3
      }
    },
    // TS Error:
    // Type '{ parameters: SpecParametersMap[T]; type: T; }' is not assignable to type 'UserSpec | ClientSpec'.
    // Type '{ parameters: SpecParametersMap[T]; type: T; }' is not assignable to type 'ClientSpec'.
    // Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
    // Type 'T' is not assignable to type '"client"'.ts(2322)
    data: {
      parameters,
      type
    }
  }
}

doThing(SpecType.CLIENT, { foo: 4 })
```

Playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgZTGGzgG8BYAKDjhgE8iAuOAAwBJTDiAVB4AXxZUaYTFEwBbYKigBnZgFckAayQQA7kir8qVUJFiIUaLLjgBVWWi4lQqJABNZBIiQrVafZu06veRADpzfABRACVBYThRcSkZeQsrKBsABTFJaTRZbV1KfWh4ZBlTPABhABsEYBQbODtqpxdiMij6JlYOG39gANKAGQBJEIA5bkiPGIz45gqqmtc02My5HMo9cAKjYpw8AEFsbAglGAARYHRkBBgECCQWjwBtZWZZGChkAHMAXWZLa1c4AAfOCzaowGyrdYGeDVBQSJrYbr3GjBcJwAC8cAA5AokliADRRfpDUYY7HYSpgrGQvIbQxtPCpdJxLIAWUwYDJ7houLQzG5NDgACMxAB%20ZhIOFCtBRHQeClzGAzSnzYiLKZZGn5QxFEw7RL-NXM5bOAUiqDiuCSiTSqBaumFYwYfWg1XYdUsuTIuDoCAQCVSmWUOVQzaHJCvOAOCDcAAWnzJAB5uHUQPZGl0%20AA%20AAUrS8cG4hImxumCI9JvZYAe3C%20VAAlMwAG4QBAODFZ73hyM4Q7HZj7PsoM4XJBXG53TECmgAehncBCIEkYHKwCiNF9-u9gs87SxCqpxZ3IlLWX56%20Pm%20YAGYLzQ5Tv%20EfBQ5MDBMOePDvJp7ZM%20dwyF4PnAcohpQ0Zxp8OaZoExIjEWZA%20n6zAACwgfWVBAA)

Comment: @captain-yossarian check this out

Comment: @jcalz check this out

Comment: @cyberwombat, do you want to create a generator function? I mean with specific syntax `function*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is in arguments. TS dont treat them as a part of one data structure.

To make it work, you should merge your arguments into one data structure.

```js
export enum SpecType {
  USER = 'user',
  CLIENT = 'client'
}

export interface Spec {
  type: `${SpecType}`
  parameters: unknown
}

export interface ClientSpecParameters {
  foo: number
}

export interface UserSpecParameters {
  bar?: number
}

export interface UserSpec extends Spec {
  type: `${SpecType.USER}`
  parameters: UserSpecParameters
}

export interface ClientSpec extends Spec {
  type: `${SpecType.CLIENT}`
  parameters: ClientSpecParameters
}

type AllowedValues = UserSpec | ClientSpec;

export interface AccountDefinition {
  [k: string]: AllowedValues
}


export const doThing = (data: AllowedValues): void => {
  const account: AccountDefinition = {
    foo: {
      type: 'client',
      parameters: {
        foo: 3
      }
    },
    data
  }
}

doThing({ type: SpecType.CLIENT, parameters: { foo: 4 } }) // ok
doThing({ type: SpecType.USER, parameters: { bar: 42 } }) // ok
```

You can also use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68296881/typescript-conditional-return-type/68297952#68297952) approach, but as you might have noticed, there is no nice destructure

> Why can't the generic param be used to get both arguments?

Yo can, in fact there are several approaches to do it. Here you have one of them:

```js
export const doThing = <T extends SpecType>(data: T extends SpecType.CLIENT ? ClientSpec : UserSpec): void => {
    const account: AccountDefinition = {
        foo: {
            type: 'client',
            parameters: {
                foo: 3
            }
        },
        data
    }
}

doThing({ type: SpecType.CLIENT, parameters: { foo: 4 } }) // ok
doThing({ type: SpecType.USER, parameters: { bar: 42 } }) // ok

doThing({ type: SpecType.USER, parameters: { foo: 4 } }) // expected error
doThing({ type: SpecType.CLIENT, parameters: { bar: 42 } }) // expected error
```

Comment: Why can't the generic param be used to get both arguments? I thought it would but that my example didn't work due to a perhaps simple mistake

Comment: @AmirSaleem no problem!

Comment: I apologize for not being clear - what I mean is that is it possible to use a generic to achieve the two distinct function parameters as I have it in my sample. Use the generic to index two maps. Ex `doThing<FOO>(SpecType.CLIENT, { foo: 4 })`

Comment: @cyberwombat but then your object inside the function should meet the requirements of generic. Pls keep in mind, TS is about static typing, not dynamic. Maybe it worth using curried function like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68316470/how-to-type-function-parameters-in-typescript-to-map-object-properties/68316526#68316526#answer-68316526 ?