# How to type function parameters in TypeScript to map object properties?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to understand how to correctly set the types to the `prop` and `value` function parameters (see the `??`) so that prop and value must match the ones defined in the `MyStorage` interface. Setting `keyof MyStorage` should be sufficient to correctly type `prop`, but then I'm completely lost on how to type `value`.

```
interface MyStorage {
  prop1?: string;
  prop2?: number;
  prop3?: boolean;
  prop4?: Array<string>;
  prop5?: 'value1' | 'value2';
}

const myStorage: MyStorage = {};

const setProp = (prop: ??, value: ??) => {
  myStorage[prop] = value;
}

setProp('prop1', 'Ok');
setProp('prop1', 5); // Not Ok
setProp('prop5', 'value1'); // Ok
setProp('prop5', 'value5'); // Not Ok
```

The ultimate goal is to transform this function to a generic version like this:

```
const genericSetProp = <T>(prop: ??, value: ??, storage: T) => {
  storage[prop] = value;
}

genericSetProp('prop1', 'Ok', myStorage);
genericSetProp('prop1', 5, myStorage); // Not Ok
genericSetProp('prop5', 'value1', myStorage); // Ok
genericSetProp('prop5', 'value5', myStorage); // Not Ok
```

How can I set those types to make TypeScript correctly check those parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the type of a member of a structure by doing `MyStorage["prop1"]` etc. To get the `"prop1"` part, you can require that `key` be `keyof MyStorage`. So the first version looks like this:

```typescript
const setProp = <K extends keyof MyStorage>(prop: K, value: MyStorage[K]) => {
    myStorage[prop] = value;
};
```

And you can indeed make that generic by having the type `MyStorage` inferred from a third argument, using a second generic type parameter:

```typescript
const genericSetProp = <T, K extends keyof T>(prop: K, value: T[K], storage: T) => {
    storage[prop] = value;
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DKYD2U4DmKA3gFDIXIAOUOVAjAPwBcyAzmFKAQNzmU06AJhbIQAVwC2AI2h9K1WlQDMo6ThwAbCHBDyBSgCyiAglHzoAPBy4gCAPn0VBVAKyiA5ADc4m8RHoPZAAfZG9ffyEPPgBfUlIEHBAOZEksXHwiVgxsPEIUAF5kYhi+BKSUtggwAAUlZCLLAGlkCAAPSBAAEzZkAGsIdBwYNHS8onsAChdWJoAaZB8-CGyxzIgAbSaAXQBKBvti-go03PWNl22GxYiIWLKq2qVJjxdAhY8AeT6PXb5Hup0F5vDwLVx-ZAAekhyAAcjgwMhvqQAc9XkpXKCwkt-IEIdCkX0UdVAVRgRiseFlpj8TD4YjkeVkoiiCBoMAEJgSfVGgAVBYtdqdHr9QbDZC8qYzZDzG7LVi8rbbBYccYrCX7AqHMgKVXnS7XHF3UileKs9mc7lA9F0d5hb5Y04ZfJ-UjmriWp7WkFghZOtW0uEIwluiBsj1cr1km1uSlGu3+9aB5HujmR0nkuiYj5G7OpNYunhQunB75AA)

Answer (score 1):

Just use extra generic:

```js
interface MyStorage {
  prop1?: string;
  prop2?: number;
  prop3?: boolean;
  prop4?: Array<string>;
  prop5?: 'value1' | 'value2';
}

const myStorage: MyStorage = {};

const setProp = <Prop extends keyof MyStorage,>(prop: Prop, value: MyStorage[Prop]) => {
  myStorage[prop] = value;
}

setProp('prop1', 'Ok');
setProp('prop1', 5); // Not Ok
setProp('prop5', 'value1'); // Ok
setProp('prop5', 'value5'); // Not Ok
```

FP approach:

```js
const withObject = <Obj,>(obj: Obj) => <Prop extends keyof MyStorage>(
  prop: Prop, value: MyStorage[Prop]
) => ({
  ...obj,
  [prop]: value
})

const setProp = withObject(myStorage)

setProp('prop1', 'Ok');
setProp('prop1', 5); // Not Ok
setProp('prop5', 'value1'); // Ok
setProp('prop5', 'value5'); // Not Ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DKYD2U4DmKA3gFDLIAOUOlAjAPwBcyAzmFKAQNzlU2UATM2QgArgFsARtF4VqtAMwipOHABsIcEHP60ALCICCUfOgA87TiAIA%20XQsoBWEQHIAbnHViIdV8gAfZA8vH0FXXgBfUlIEHBB2ZAksXHwiFgxsPEIUAF5kYkjeWPjEgHdgMAALAHkpACsIBDBkfPM6%20oAaWwAKHAaWDoBKVttkcwAFAWQIAA9IEAATVmQAawh0HBg0FOyiXr5HFinaTuRPbwgM3bSIAG0TygBdUhHcsZ6yCgA6X-6uvh3RxPFgXHykSJDGJxBItVgQMCPVrICrVDpNMA9ZJZW5Q0jwxECHquRx%20M6uGqrVxDXgEx7E0muM5OGnIAD0bOQADkcC1KfiEfSSQInEzgmDfNTuOzOfy6UThbRReSJaLWRzubzkJSgA)

Comment: You may not have seen the second part of the question asking how to do this generically. :-)