# React props - struggling with discriminating union types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-proptypes, discriminated-union, union-types

I have two components with similar props, but there is a crucial difference.  One component, called `TabsWithState` takes only a single prop `tabs`, which is an array of objects of the following shape:

```
interface ItemWithState {
  name: string;
  active: boolean;
}

interface WithStateProps {
  tabs: ItemWithState[];
};
```

Another similar component, called `TabsWithRouter`, requires the item shape to be different:

```
interface ItemWithRouter {
  name: string;
  path: string;
}

interface WithRouterProps {
  tabs: ItemWithRouter[];
};
```

I am trying to create a generic component `Tabs`, which would account for both scenarios.  I want to be able to write a `<Tabs />` component, where if a `withRouter` prop is passed, the `tabs` property must be of type `ItemWithRouter[]`.  But if no `withRouter` prop is passed, it must of type `ItemWithState[]`.  Also, if `withRouter` is passed, `Tabs` should also accept an optional `baseUrl` prop.

I tried creating a discriminating union type, like this:

```
type WithStateProps = {
  withRouter?: never;
  baseUrl?: never;
  tabs: ItemWithState[];
};

type WithRouterProps = {
  withRouter: boolean;
  baseUrl?: string;
  tabs: ItemWithRouter[];
};

type TabsProps = WithStateProps | WithRouterProps;
```

In my generic `Tabs` component, I want to render `TabsWithRouter` if `withRouter` is present, and `TabsWithState` if `withRouter` is not present:

```
const Tabs = (props: TabsProps) => {
  const { withRouter } = props;
  if (withRouter) {
    return <TabsWithRouter {...props} />;
  }
  return <TabsWithState {...props} />;
};
```

I initially tried to define `TabsWithRouter` and `TabsWithState` as being function components that accept `WithRouterProps` and `WithStateProps`, respectively:

```
const TabsWithRouter: React.FC<WithRouterProps> = (props: WithRouterProps) => { ... }
const TabsWithState: React.FC<WithStateProps> = (props: WithStateProps) => { ... }
```

But I get the error `Types of property 'withRouter' are incompatible. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.`, as can be seen in [this ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=4&ts=4.1.0-dev.20201028#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4BYAKCuADsYkpN0k4BJBkAdWBgAsAyjBQM4Abypw4tFCCQAuOAGcYUOgHMKlKehjAAbgrgAjCBAA2qWloC+VGvUbM0rDkm68+CCAFcGUcUlpWSMVNVpNILARPkUwjVt7ShgATzBWHn4hESQABRwwJTgAXkDtOAB3T28-RgB+RVokQygtKWMUJSQAVShzBulmxja4YWMlRTcPLOEGAG0AXVstKlT0uEyvX398iEKSsqkq-hr-RVMLKxGOrt7+uNUEoLGJ9k5N08ZF5aS11gAVFDjXb7UqbbIMEFFAA+G2q20YUJWlDQEFoKjggPGHwRUEUyF0ADoAGIAYQAPDjalAoQA+A4ACjABVeVJ2LIAlCV6RJyqj0fAxKMgUUbAdmXslCN+UpLoTzBB1AyXnMAAwLQnRfgcoJEGA+KC0aQ+czmKh2FFojFYpTg2ZGAkYEkUu05OmMiWFRSuyGc7mHOAywXC8ZwMWlT1SoIyuUKpUq9WE3QGJA68p6g1G2gms2UC1UIOYkUelmKG1QrnFHnRq3B45balh8UskbATBwBn1z5QLm8qRSDOGuDkm1sxjiQmTyNigD0tJG+fTSH1Q5HIp9rDEk81LNn8-NyML-yQGNKDMr1aXK6NDKCUnJABMDLS7-216GZzO4fxA9AiBhlHtOBI1ffsQyUYoxDmIUZDkRQAHIQBSWCkHggAaOBk0MRRVB8VgbAWC0wKkOdQOHG04E-b8+DgOhUSgf94BUHJgJZMj2k6Ho+mKfBZTkfgNHwdjwMg6DgjguBEOQkJ0MwjAUxwqA8LDQiyNI8owPfIoqK4DgaPoxi4BwRsQI04iu1xYSXlEmCQgQpCUNkrVYkkvikGc+CVKI4j1OI8jix0vTfwYpAAOM-xWMlYSLOpYSbi48weLcg1zCEsywOsqDbIkqTHIw5yELcjyvLUl90v8j8v10n86L-UL4HC8dTL8o54Vi8qpEysSUPs6S5FkrCjFw-DVPK9TX3JGcn30MqpDTRcgA)

So I tried instead to type `TabsWithRouter` and `TabsWithState` as accepting `TabsProps` as their props:

```
const TabsWithRouter: React.FC<TabsProps> = (props: TabsProps) => {
  const { tabs } = props;
  console.log(tabs[0].path)
  return null
}
const TabsWithState: React.FC<TabsProps> = (props: TabsProps) => {
  const { tabs } = props;
  console.log(tabs[0].active)
  return null
}
```

But in this case, trying to access `tabs[x].path` or `tabs[x].active` gives me the error `Property 'active' does not exist on type 'ItemWithState | ItemWithRouter'. Property 'active' does not exist on type 'ItemWithRouter'`, as can be seen in [*this* ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=4&ts=4.1.0-dev.20201028#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4BYAKCuADsYkpN0k4BJBkAdWBgAsAyjBQM4Abypw4tFCCQAuOAGcYUOgHMKlKehjAAbgrgAjCBAA2qWloC+VGvUbM0rDkm68+CCAFcGUcUlpWSMVNVpNILARPkUwjVt7ShgATzBWHn4hESQABRwwJTgAXkDtOAB3T28-RgB+RVokQygtKWMUJSQAVShzBulmxja4YWMlRTcPLOEGAG0AXVstKlT0uEyvX398iEKSsqkq-hr-RVMLKxGOrt7+uNUEoLGJ9k5N08ZF5aS11gAVFDjXb7UqbbIMEFFAA+G2q20YUJWlDQEFoKjggPGHwRUEUyF0ADoAGIAYQAPFilFCAHwHAAUYAKrypUIAlCU6RJyqj0fAxKMgUUbAcmXslCNeUpLoTzBB1PSXnMAAwLQnRfhsoJEGA+KC0aQ+czmKh2FFojFU8GzIwEjAkims5l00qM5mKJ3ijnFLlBKX8wXjOAi0piwqSi0yuUKpWqwm6AxILXlHV6g20I0myhmqj+zFChlhllC9mcw5wPMC45bWoBENwIsjYCYOD06ufKAc7lSKSp-VwSlCnG18SEsdFkUAehpIxzKaQuv7g+xnghrDEY-VzKnM9NyLz-yQGNd3t988XBvpQSk5IAJgYadee8uipPJ3D+BXoEQMMobQ3mSfHtAyUYoxDmAUZDkRQAHIQBSKCkBggAaOAE0MRRVB8VgbAWM1gKkacgIHKk4DfD8+DgOhUSgH94BUHIAPFYj2k6Ho+mKfBpTkfgNHwFiQLAiDgmguA4IQkIULQjBE0wqBsODPDiKI8pgJfMj3y4DhKJoui4BwEciwE9tcQEl4hMgkJYPgxCpI1WIxO4pB7JgxT8IIlSCJIgtyK0z9dKQX8DP8JjCmM+FawEm52PMTinL1cx+NUgjzPAyzRPE2zUPs2CnJctzlMfZKb1I3ztKo2gAqC3FQqUcKTlM4qe1S4TEOsiS5Ck9CjCwnClKalSn3JSd730IqpGTOcgA).

Interestingly, in both cases, when I actually try to *use* the component, the props are behaving correctly, as can be seen in some examples at the bottom of either ts playground.

I feel like I'm close, but I'm struggling to get these discriminating union types to behave in the way that I want so that typescript stops erroring.  I've read many posts on here asking similar questions, but I can't seem to apply them to what is going wrong in my scenario.

### Edit:

As per request, here is my tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.paths.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "types": [
      "cypress",
      "cypress-file-upload",
      "jest"
    ],
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

### Edit2

[this ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-g4ffqyPH0-MEggxOupAIWDZtanvddOyXTc8UsRVp2nJ8GjgI8j3+SQ4EFBgMG0NNaVvOC4NOKocHaPBomsAAiEBsjI8jsDMSxrF0EJ+BITo3HwpDYPwhDKmQ1CJA5dgMJVbDilw-tILg9ZNh2BwqnIrRqCQSQDHIyTp0I4jSNUCiqJouiMAYzQmJYtj1JPdSeKQlCRCEAThKwqh-XEip1KUYdhn9Ny6hrIiSOUHTNEo6idNo2kUiCxS1GSSRyNIMyOIsjirL42y0Ic+AnPCFytG8jzRygbzpO2XZ5KipA1wcNSOJOXytICmI4GC-TwskSKlJiiQ4tY9j8KS7jk2swY7MEjK4Cy3dFxquB8s9bzNP8sigr00KDPMKxjKgZj4t6uD+qUeEj2giwuIdH9DCAA) shows that captain-yossarian's solution doesn't enforce the kinds of types I'm looking to enforce on the `Tabs` component

Comment: I made an update, seems it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something simple like this... giving TypeScript a hint using `as WithRouterProps` or `as WithStateProps` as appropriate?

```
const Tabs = (props: TabsProps) => {
  const { withRouter } = props;
  if (withRouter !== undefined) {
    return <TabsWithRouter {...props as WithRouterProps} />;
  }
  return <TabsWithState {...props as WithStateProps} />;
};
```

Comment: I ended up doing this just to get typescript to stop complaining.  Its a nice solution and still enforces discrimination types as needed in this scenario.  It does feel like a bit of a hack.  I'll leave this unanswered for a day or so in hopes of inspiring someone to come up with a more 'proper' answer - if not, I'll mark it as the answer.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Control flow of [aliased conditions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4-beta/#cfa-aliased-conditions) is available only since `ts@4.4`. So, using *destructured* `withRouter` variable doesn't carry any type information when used inside `if` statement before `ts@4.4`.

Then there is a subtle issue in your code. Your `withRouter` prop has type `boolean` and here:

```ts
const Tabs = (props: TabsProps) => {
  const { withRouter } = props;
  if (withRouter) { // withRouter === true
    return <TabsWithRouter {...props} />;
  }
  return <TabsWithState {...props} />;
};
```

You're narrowing it's type to `true` not to `boolean` (`true | false`).

Another issue is optional types always bring `undefined` value into the union. Thus you have to explicitly check for such a case. This check simultaneously check for explicit 'undefined' value *or* the case when `!('withRouter' in props)`:

```ts
const Tabs = (props: TabsProps) => {
  if (props.withRouter === undefined) {
      return <TabsWithState {...props} />;
  }  
  
  return <TabsWithRouter {...props} />;
};
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/N52E5m)

Since `ts@4.4` you can use desctructured `withRouter` as aliased condition:

```ts
const Tabs = (props: TabsProps) => {
  const { withRouter } = props
  if (withRouter === undefined) {
      return <TabsWithState {...props} />;
  }  
  
  return <TabsWithRouter {...props} />;
};
```

[playground check](https://tsplay.dev/NDG58w)

Comment: Interesting...my project is using 4.2.4.  I switched your example's version to 4.2.3, and theystill work in the playground, but not in my project.  In my project, I still get errors about `Types of property 'withRouter' are incompatible. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.`. Not sure what I'm missing

Comment: Can you post contents of your `tsconfig.json` file?

Comment: I added it to the question

Comment: I assume `tsconfig.paths.json` does not contain any significant compiler options?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-moore-x637f?file=/src/App.tsx still cannot reproduce with exact ts version and the same `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234704/discussion-between-seth-lutske-and-aleksxor).

Comment: I see that it works fine in the ts playground and the codesandbox, for the life of me I cannot see what the difference is in my actual codebase that is causing this error to persist.  Ultimately I'm going to use @ChrisFarmer's solution, inelegant as it is, because I can't really spend more time on this.  Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You could define a single `TabsProps` type:

```
type TabsProps = {
  withRouter: boolean;
  baseUrl?: string;
  tabs: ItemWithRouter[] | ItemWithState[];
};
```

and use it in your interface specific components like:

```
const TabsWithRouter: React.FC<TabsProps> = (props: TabsProps) => {
  const tabs = props.tabs as ItemWithRouter[];
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>TabsWithRouter Path: {tabs[0].path}</h3>
    </div>
  );
};

const TabsWithState: React.FC<TabsProps> = (props: TabsProps) => {
  const tabs = props.tabs as ItemWithState[];
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>TabsWithState Path: {tabs[0].active ? "true" : "false"}</h3>
    </div>
  );
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-ptolemy-s2r3n

Comment: ...mmm, no.  This does not work. For example, if I create a `Tabs` component with `withRouter={true}`, I do not get an error when trying to give it a `tabs` property that has `active` entries in each `tab`.  [See example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-sun-y91bo?file=/src/App.tsx). This does not help me enforce one type of `tab` object vs another based on the status or existence of the `withRouter` prop.  The `tabs` type can't just be either/or willy-nilly, it has to be based on the value for `withRouter`.  Thank you for putting in the time though

Answer (score 1):

Because both union have `withROuter` prop, it is hard for TS to distinguish them.

I think union worth refactoring.

**UPDATE** - added overloading

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react'

interface ItemWithState {
  name: string;
  active: boolean;
}


interface ItemWithRouter {
  name: string;
  path: string;
}


type WithStateProps = {
  tabs: ItemWithState[];
};

type WithRouterProps = {
  withRouter: true;
  baseUrl?: string;
  tabs: ItemWithRouter[];
};

type TabsProps = WithStateProps | WithRouterProps;

const hasProperty = <Obj, Prop extends string>(obj: Obj, prop: Prop)
  : obj is Obj & Record<Prop, unknown> =>
  Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);


const TabsWithRouter: FC<WithRouterProps> = (props: WithRouterProps) => null
const TabsWithState: FC<WithStateProps> = (props: WithStateProps) => null

type Overloading =
  & ((props: WithStateProps) => JSX.Element)
  & ((props: WithRouterProps) => JSX.Element)

const Tabs: Overloading = (props: TabsProps) => {
  if (hasProperty(props, 'withRouter')) {
    return <TabsWithRouter {...props} />;
  }
  return <TabsWithState {...props} />;
};

const Test = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Tabs // With correct state props
        tabs={[{ name: "myname", active: true }]}
      />
      <Tabs // With incorrect state props
        baseUrl="something"
        tabs={[{ name: "myname", active: true }]}
      />
      <Tabs // WIth correct router props
        withRouter
        tabs={[{ name: "myname", path: "somepath" }]}
      />
      <Tabs // WIth correct router props
        withRouter
        baseUrl="someurl"
        tabs={[{ name: "myname", path: "somepath" }]}
      />
      <Tabs // WIth incorrect router props
        withRouter
        tabs={[{ name: "myname", active: true }]}
      />
    </div>
  );
```

Now, TS is able to figure out where is `withState` and where is `withRouter`

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-d9i-KB8Ox-4kJPWM6k88zjXuA5642EjnQ5pk0uYzgTMByHBSfrjTlZ1psLQZpIrtxaIzozelCUBgYBCKB2DgeFk3DbhcFVODQzIAB6YlVlIExgNA8DIL3At+BwOD1UjJCUOYEgQUTV0kAhYNl1qDCwIfEwlHhRsLEVQDAOwho4EQxD-kkOBBQYDBtDTWlIyYji6j3KocHaPBomsAAiEBskUpTsDMSxrCWfgSE6NwpJ49ipK4ypeP4iQOXYISVVE4pxI7SSOPWTYdgcKolK0agkEkAwlOcwDTlk+TlFUZTVPUzSMG0xYoGWUgDMC5DArMni+JEIQrNskSqH9RyKkCpRP2Gf0iukhoQoU8LNBUtTwo02kUlq7y1GSSQlMSwypJSoy0oszKBJy+A8vCAqtHKkrvygcrXO2XZPNapBQIcAKjJOGS5OqmI4DqqKmskFqfPaiROv07qON60zk3SwYsus4a4FGmDQ0mhdwnK4KtrCna9oa6LzCsOKEvO5KTOYxDWJMh1SMMIA)

Btw, both [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68296881/typescript-conditional-return-type/68297952#68297952) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68304681/correct-ts-declaration-for-mapping-fields-together/68308088#68308088) questions might be interesting for you.
TS does not play well with destructuring in term of working with unions

Comment: Your solution doesn't appear to throw the proper errors when the props are passed incorrectly to an instance of `<Tabs />` - ts playground link is too long for a comment, but if you copy the `Test` component from my examples into the end of your example, you'll see there are no proper errors thrown for incorrect scenarios.  In my actual project, feeding a `tabs` object to `<Tabs />` that is of type `ItemWithRouter[]` without a `withRouter` property shows no error, and a tabs type of `ItemWithState[]` *with* `withRouter` does not error either

Comment: @SethLutske do you mean `Tabs` component instead `Test`? I'm bit confused. Why do I need to use your component since I fixed it? COuld you please provide a link in your question?

Comment: I added a link at the end of my question, edit 2.  Ultimately the purpose of all this is to enforce certain props on the `Tabs` component.  When I write `<Tabs withRouter tabs={sometabs} />`, `someTabs` will have to contain a `path` property on each entry.  Your solution doesn't seem to be enforcing that, or vice versa

Comment: Its working!  This is another nice solution.  I wish I could award two answers

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of how you can narrow down the right type in this case

#### With an additional `tag` attribute

```
type WithStateProps = {
  tag: 'WithState'  
  withRouter?: boolean;
  baseUrl?: boolean;
  tabs: string[];
};

type WithRouterProps = {
  tag: 'WithRouter'  
  withRouter: boolean;
  baseUrl?: string;
  tabs: string[];
};

type TabsProps = WithStateProps | WithRouterProps

const Tabs = (props: TabsProps) => {
  if (props.tag === 'WithRouter') {
    return <TabsWithRouter {...props} />; // ✅ (parameter) props: WithRouterProps
  }
  return <TabsWithState {...props} />; // ✅ (parameter) props: WithStateProps
};
```

[Sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.3#code/C4TwDgpgBA6glsAFgZWAQ2BACgJwPZgDOUAvFAN4BQUU6A5gFxQDkqGEzN1UA7gogCU8AV0w4A-EwBGePABsIaAHYBublLSEIAVRxzJUGfMWru6KYSaFgOOEroBtALpqAvmsqhIsfkNEQcXAJiMioaeiZmPzFOKG4+JGiA6VkFZTUaDS1dfSsbOzoM2jQLPNt7ZzcPL2gAFRLCIKJSHyQ2TCbiAB9WwRExTspKAGM8JWsoeosWgAowfCImKcaFwgBKUgA+Cm5R8eAKXl9+gKhXFvngorgAMyg51YA6elISMiiTnGYNsJooHAgwGEOCUUEuRCKrm4AKBILBqyqQ0oN2ESmGwDgYygcEI8ESn06D2CTDxKHQHVWUB6pKSgVWayY4OION6tM6OxoMOBoKJzU0rIJ9MeCT6-hwUAAhG8oKiACYQG52CCytxDPYTZYADVmTKWDU6GxI21+6oO5CO+LFZwuCO4t3uOJpguCvPWP24nMB3PhV24UM9sNBTKqQA)

#### Using [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)

```
type WithStateProps = {
  withRouter?: boolean;
  baseUrl?: boolean;
  tabs: string[];
};

type WithRouterProps = {
  withRouter: boolean;
  baseUrl?: string;
  tabs: string[];
};

type TabsProps = WithStateProps | WithRouterProps

const Tabs = (props: TabsProps) => {
  if (isWithRouterProps(props)) {
    return <TabsWithRouter {...props} />; // ✅ (parameter) props: WithRouterProps
  }
  return <TabsWithState {...props} />; // ✅ (parameter) props: WithStateProps
};

function isWithRouterProps(props: WithStateProps | WithRouterProps): props is WithRouterProps {
  return (props as WithRouterProps).withRouter !== undefined;
}
```

[Sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.3#code/C4TwDgpgBA6glsAFgZWAQ2BACgJwPZgDOUAvFAN4BQUUA7gogEp4CumOA-AFxQBGeeADYQ0AOwDc1PmkIQAqjkHc+A4WMk10vQj0LAccUQHMA2gF1JAX0mVQkWA2ZsIOXAWJkqNekifse-EIiElK8MvKKynoGxhpQWjpQ0YamFpTWlLbg0AAqaNpuRKQOSKgY2PhFAD4lTKzshYSZAMZ4onpQedrFABRglYldhI0AlKQAfBRScABmUD1whPC+9S6NfQMjY140UDgQwCw4olAAPEPLdc44FAB09-3ullAA9OPiry9QgKDk82BoODQAFsDi4xo8iDxLn41gMpJYpPtDsczhcGGVMHcHgNnm8Pi8vr8+gDgaCcOCBlD0ehMI10jYZixRM1gHA2lBFtDVq4Bht3FTSjSKu4oDUuddRjwIcRFrUYTyRTskUcTnyijI5dzRrcfFd2FAAIQkMhMgAmEBmhggpqsQA)

[Extended sandbox for your specific case](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-AwJNQyYlAwYCEoOw4PDkz2IjhVRvQ2QAPTE1akExjuBYyeRkyz+eL5c1gv8debyM7vfMEi9cjijDAMEclMA-3ffsKnzQJPlKSM4D+Vcm00UMf3+SQrl7AdagvBdO1gjZ4OGf8i1VGYEM9OAAEIqhqcU8SQcgOCQPFMgTF04AeJAIWDZsUKQOc0NJaclzxSxFRHEdrwaOBt23LC4EFBgMG0NNaTPQTBNOKocHaPBomsAAiEBsg0zTsDMSxrF0EJ+BITo3EU0SBMU4TKjEiSOCklVZOKeSBx4wT1k2HYHCqTStGoDiJAMTTPJHZTVPU1QtJ0vSDM-KxNBMsyLPC3dwrs0TxJEIQJEk6BpPgKh-XcipwqUfDsPCCq6hrFS1OUGLNG03SYv02kUhawK1GSSRNNINKrIyqysoc3LJAKqAirgErwjKrRaqqxCoFq7ztl2fyeqQecHDCqyTnqqKmpiOBWvizrJG6oK+okAbzMsxSRts5NssGPKOXYZyZLm7gFqWv8aoOuqGga6LTvO9qEvMJK6igUzBsewTnqUeFtz4iwbIdF9DCAA)