# Display different components depending on props: TypeError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, switch-statement

I am currently trying to create a type safe implementation of an component that takes its props and displays different components depending on its props.

I have tried a number of different approaches but no matter what, I get TypeErrors.

My current approach is this:

```
import React from 'react';

interface Props<brand, type> {
    identification: {
        brand: brand,
        type: type
    };
    id: number;
}

type Comp1Props = Props<'one', 'a'>;

const Comp1:React.FC<Comp1Props> = props => <div>{JSON.stringify(props)}</div>;

type Comp2Props = Props<'one', 'b'>;

const Comp2:React.FC<Comp2Props> = props => <div>{JSON.stringify(props)}</div>;

type Comp3Props = Props<'two', 'b'>;

const Comp3:React.FC<Comp3Props> = props => <div>{JSON.stringify(props)}</div>;

type AllComps = Comp1Props | Comp2Props | Comp3Props;

const Panel:React.FC<AllComps> = (props) => {
    const { brand, type } = props.identification;
    if( brand === 'one' ){
        if (type === 'a') {
            return <Comp1 {...props} />; // TypeError
        }
        if (type === 'b') {
            return <Comp2 {...props} />; // TypeError
        }
    }
    if( brand === 'two' ){
        if (type === 'b') {
            return <Comp3 {...props} />; // TypeError
        }
    }
    return <div />;
};

const Display: React.FC<AllComps> = (props) => (
    <Panel {...props} />
)

export default Display;
```

I get following Error Message:

```
Type '{ identification: { brand: "one"; type: "a"; }; id: number; } | { identification: { brand: "one"; type: "b"; }; id: number; } | { identification: { brand: "two"; type: "b"; }; id: number; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Comp1Props'.
  Type '{ identification: { brand: "one"; type: "b"; }; id: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Comp1Props'.
    The types of 'identification.type' are incompatible between these types.
      Type '"b"' is not assignable to type '"a"'.ts(2322)
```

I am bumping my heads against a wall for hours now, not finding a sufficient solution to make a concept like this possible and type safe, I guess I am having some fundamental misunderstanding here.

I would really appreciate all information that possibly leads me to a solution for this kind of Problem. I can't imagine I am the first one who tries to create a 'switch-component' with more than one switch-prop.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can declare custom [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) for each type `const isComp1 = (props: AllComps): props is Comp1Props => props.identification.brand === 'one' && props.identification.type === 'a'` and then use them `if( isComp1(props)){ return <Comp1 {...props} />; }` [playground](https://tsplay.dev/WylMxm)

Answer (score 0):

Destructuring messes up with typescript

Try:

```
const Panel:React.FC<AllComps> = (props) => {
    if( props.identification.brand === 'one' ){
        if (props.identificationtype === 'a') {
            return <Comp1 {...props} />;
        }
        if (props.identification.type === 'b') {
            return <Comp2 {...props} />;
        }
    }
    if( props.identification.brand === 'two' ){
        if (props.identification.type === 'b') {
            return <Comp3 {...props} />;
        }
    }
    return <div />;
};
```

Comment: This is producing essentially the same error message: `Type '{ identification: { brand: "one"; type: "a"; }; id: number; } | { identification: { brand: "one"; type: "b"; }; id: number; } | { identification: { brand: "two"; type: "b"; }; id: number; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Comp1Props'.
  Type '{ identification: { brand: "one"; type: "b"; }; id: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Comp1Props'.
    Types of property 'identification' are incompatible.
      Type '{ brand: "one"; type: "b"; }' is not assignable to type '{ brand: "one"; type: "a"; }'.ts(2322)`

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68308390/react-props-struggling-with-discriminating-union-types